# Does tex support `\begin{align}`?

Tags: math-mode, align

The `\tag` syntax works well with jupyter notebook

```
\begin{align}
a
&= b+1 \\
&= c+2 \tag{3-2}
\end{align}
```

[image]

However, it causes error with [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)

> LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.

[image]

Does it mean tex doesn't support `\begin{align}` or I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: that environment is defined by the amsmath package that you have not loaded

Comment: tex (the program) doesn't support any latex environment  `begin{...}` all such syntax is defined by macros in the latex format or loaded packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much. Would you consider moving your comment to answer? I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `align` environment is defined by the `amsmath` package that you have not loaded.